# Unable to test a controller for service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a code to test the service call which is done in my controller . I am trying to unit test that particular function in controller which is doing the service call and bringing the data . Currently i am trying with local json , but it will actually do a service call .

I got to know that first i have create a spy object but i am getting the error as "TypeError: jasmine.CreateSpyObj is not a function" , i am new to unit testing . I am unable to create a spyobject so unable to proceed further .Pasting my code , request you to help me please.

Also i am not sure what exactly i have to do once i successfully create spyObject , i actually want to test if my service is getting hit fine and i am getting response from service.

Please help me i am stryggling in this from many days now.

Service code :

```
//app is the module name
app.factory('appServices', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, 
$http) {
var appServices = {};
appServices.getData = function(){
      return $http.get(scripts/services/data/unitTesting.json'); 
 };
```

unitTesting.json code :

```
{
"name":"unit testing",
"countryCode": "EG",
"countryName": "Egypt",
"region": "Africa"
}
```

Controller Code :

```
getData: function(){
        appServices.getData().then(function(response) {
            if (response && response.data) {
                $scope.testVariable= response.data.name;
            }
        });
    },
```

Unit Test Code :

```
  describe('myCtrl', function() {
      beforeEach(module('app'));

      var $controller;

      beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
         $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

 describe('service call test', function() {
 var $http,$httpBackend,appServices,
 myService,$q,$rootScope,controller;

 var mockItem = 
       {
       "name":"unit testing",
       "countryCode": "EG",
       "countryName": "Egypt",
       "region": "Africa"
       }
 beforeEach(inject(function(_$http_,_$httpBackend_,appServices,_$q_, 
 _$rootScope_) {
   $http = _$http_;
   $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_; 
   appServices = appServices; 
   $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
   $q =_$q_;
   jasmine.spyOn(appServices, 'getData').and.returnValue($q.when(mockItem));
   controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
 }));
  it('Service call test ', function() {
  controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $rootScope.new() });
  controller.getData();
  expect(appServices.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }); 
 });
 });
```

ERROR :

```
 TypeError: jasmine.spyOn is not a function
```

Comment: It should be in lowercase: `jasmine.createSpyObj`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help its my mistake . Can you please tell the further steps in this for testing that my service call is successful or not . I have seen many solutions online and i find them confusing . It would be great if you can help with  further steps .

Comment: Which version of Jasmine are you using?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney its  jasmin - 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the `spyOn` function:

```
jasmine.spyOn(appServices, 'getData');
```

You can then check for calls in your tests like:

```
expect(appServices.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Looking at how you have written your spec, can I suggest some other changes to help you get it to run:

```
var $rootScope,
    controller,
    $q;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$http_,_$httpBackend_,appServices,_$q_, _$rootScope_){
     $http = _$http_;
     $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_; 
     appServices= appServices;
     $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
     $q = _$q_;
     jasmine.spyOn(appServices, 'getData').and.returnValue($q.when(mockItem));
     controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
}));
describe('when fetching data in the controller', function(){
    it('should delegate the call to appServices.getData()', function() {
        controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $rootScope.new() });
        controller.getData();
        expect(appServices.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @Vitaliy Gorbenko , i have edited my unit test code edited my question accordingly but i still get the error . Please have a look at my code edited the original question with error message .

Comment: Is there any way to connect separately with you . I feel i am missing something important in my code.